# How to call a procedure in main activity when a widget is clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

i have an activity (MainForm.java) that have procedure for showing toast..
here's the code:

```
package com.application.TestingWidget3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainForm extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        onlyToast();
    }

    public void onlyToast()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Only Showing Toast", 1).show();
    }
}
```

what should i do on my HelloWidget.java for call the onlyToast() procedure when the widget is clicked once??

here'e my HelloWidget code:

```
package com.application.TestingWidget3;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;

public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    // What should i do here??
}
```

really need your help.. thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nice tutorial for application widget you have to see it once

[Application Widget](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your MainForm instance as a parameter to your HelloWidget constructor. Then you have access to the public methods of MainForm from within your HelloWidget class.

Comment: Thanks John for your answer.. have a nice day.. :)